# discord.js putting an image on another image

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, image-manipulation, jimp

I've been trying to make a command that when you send an image or a url of an image it puts that image on another image that I already have in the code and I keep getting errors every time I try changing it to either `imageTemp` (which is the image you put your image on) or ``` image`` or ``` messageAttachment```. I'll put my code below so you could see what the problem is.

```
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const Jimp = require('jimp');
const discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
  name: "img",
  aliases: [],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    let messageAttachment = message.attachments.size > 0 ? message.attachments.array()[0].url : null
    try {
      let imageTemp = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Banana-Single.jpg"
      let image = await Jimp.read(messageAttachment);
      let buffer = await image.getBufferAsync(Jimp.MIME_JPEG);

    Jimp.read(imageTemp).then(image => {
    image.composite(messageAttachment, 10, 10)
    })

      message.channel.send(new MessageAttachment(buffer));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      message.channel.send('Oops, there was an error. Try inputting the command again.');
    }
  },
};
```

And here's the result and the errors I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnTkn.jpg

[image: result]

Comment: Can u please show us the Error what you get?

Comment: yeah [here](https://imgur.com/a/C6RcTOf)

Comment: I'm using replit.com by the way

Comment: @ceqoX I forgot to mention your user sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Jimp.composite()` method accepts a `Jimp` image object as its first argument. Not an url (`messageAttachment`) as you are passing in. Also you are saving the image to buffer before you modify it.

And the error you mentioned occurs when `messageAttachment` is `null`. You should check and return if the message has no attachments.

```js
const imageTemp = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Banana-Single.jpg";
const messageAttachment = message.attachments.size > 0 ? message.attachments.array()[0].url : null;

// Exit if there is no message attachment present in the message
if (!messageAttachment) return;

// Resolve the temporary image url to Jimp object
const firstImage = await Jimp.read(imageTemp);
// Resolve the message attachment image url to Jimp object
const secondImage = await Jimp.read(messageAttachment);

// Composite the two images together (modifies the firstImage object)
firstImage.composite(secondImage, 10, 10);

// Save the resulting image to buffer
const buffer = await firstImage.getBufferAsync(Jimp.MIME_JPEG);

// Send the buffer as a message attachment
message.channel.send("Combined image:", {files: [{ attachment: buffer }]});
```

[image]

Comment: I've gotten another error showing that it couldn't find MIME for Buffer <null>. I'm not sure what that means since I did what you shown

Comment: Could you show me the whole error message and where does it occur?

Comment: Seems like [this](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/issues/643) issue.

Comment: here's the entire error message https://imgur.com/a/LzgqeX0

Comment: I'm guessing it is throwing the error on line with `Jimp.read()`, is that correct? More precisely the one with `messageAttachment`. Could you do `console.log(messageAttachment)`? And show me what the ouput is?

Comment: Btw I tested it using, discord.js `^12.5.3` and jimp `^0.16.1`.

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/NJNXyyJM) is my whole code. You can test the code on your device and then try implement it into your own bot. Sadly, I'm unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I added the console.log thing but it keep giving me the same error

Comment: I've got this error now about the url https://imgur.com/a/xfayy2E

Comment: @cupded The `console.log` isn't supposed to fix your error, it's supposed to **debug it**.

Comment: @cupded Show me your current code, how did you implement my code inside your bot. It's the same error, meaning what you are passing to `Jimp.read()` is `null`...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zUYPU4iS i changed the Jimp.MIME_JPEG to PNG instead seeing if anything would work too

Comment: The code looks ok, did you save your source files and restarted the bot correctly?

Comment: Yes I restarted the bot and have all the files

Comment: I've finally got the code to work, the problem was that the temporary image needed to be in the image assets folder. Not as a link.

Comment: That's weird... But I'm glad, that it finally works.